# MySQL equal to X and greater than Y

Tags: mysql

Having ones of those moments..

Basically all I want to do is say

```
SELECT * FROM gg_Crates WHERE minutes...
```

> equal -1 AND also bring back result for where minutes is greater than
>   or equal to X

X is a variable so the results will always bring back the -1 as well as anything greater than X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT * FROM gg_Crates 
  WHERE minutes = -1 
     OR minutes >= X
```

Comment: That's what I initially though, but does that not read it to bring back results of -1 OR >= X.  Not both?

Comment: 'Bring me both apples and oranges' => 'bring me fruits that are either apples or oranges'.

Comment: Ah now I know why it doesn't work properly.  It's not my query, it's how I'm manipulating data.  My unlimited figure is -1 so it will bring everything back.  Might need to edit my Php so if unlimited is selected it doesn't do the OR statements

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this query,

```
SELECT * FROM gg_Crates WHERE minutes = -1 
UNION
SELECT * FROM gg_Crates WHERE minutes >= X
```

Comment: No special reasons. Just showing another way to do it and hoping to get some points :)

Comment: I will give you some points if you show me what it could be good for :-) I _can_ think of a reason :-) Hint: indexes

Comment: There are no duplicates if you use UNION, otherwise go for UNION ALL. Is that it ?

Comment: There are no duplicates if you use `OR` either. What I meant: When you use UNION, the executor can run two separate queries and merge their results. This means that it can use two separate indexes (or the same index twice). If you do `OR`, that would be one query with an un-indexable condition. The executor might not be smart enough to notice the equivalent UNION expression that _can_ be indexed.